# Executing Perl/CGI script in AJAX without using server

Tags: ajax, perl, cgi

I am having a Perl and a CGI file through which I want to fetch data from database. I've a UI where I am trying to use AJAX call which will hit the perl (*.pl) or (*.cgi) file and get the response in JSON. I've checked the perl/cgi file by running through command prompt and it works fine. This is how I am running my code in `command prompt`:

`D:\>PerlExecutables\strawberry_32\perl\bin\perl.exe C:\Users\UserXYZ\Desktop\PerlExamples\test.cgi`

The reason is I cannot do any kind of installation on my machine and also I don't want to run it through server like `Apache` or `IIS`.
How can this be achieved? Is there any way to make the script work in AJAX by passing the `perl.exe` path for execution or Any other alternatives?

**Thanks!**

Comment: If you can run Perl and deploy a CGI script, you can also deploy a Perl program that acts as a web server on localhost. An HTTP server will definitely need to be involved, the browser will not allow you to run programs directly.

Comment: You might want to check perl based web server, http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Server/CGI

Comment: @Thilo I found https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Daemon but everytime the URL keeps on changing if you can just run the example provided

Comment: @Ashraf.Shk786: You can specify a port number in the constructor. See the example on the page you linked to.

Comment: I am trying with `use HTTP::Daemon` for server and as soon as I run the file `server.pl` from `cmd` something happens that make command prompt non-editable which I probably think is a server start. I've also printed the url and port number which are used to call that server. But, when I try to open browser and run the URL with port number I am getting `Error 403   :  The website declined to show this webpage`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use [Plack::App::CGIBin](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::App::CGIBin). It allows you to mount CGI scripts as apps with the PSGI/[Plack](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack) protocol.

```
use Plack::App::CGIBin;
use Plack::Builder;

my $app = Plack::App::CGIBin->new(root => "/path/to/cgi-bin")->to_app;
builder {
    mount "/cgi-bin" => $app;
};
```

Save that as `myapp.psgi` (or whatever your stuff is called) and run it like this:

```
$ plackup myapp.psgi
```

By default it will open up a server on port 3000 on localhost. You will need to be able to install Perl modules. Since you have Strawberry Perl that shouldn't be a problem. In the worst case, just use a local::lib.

You will also need to be able to open a port for listening. If you cannot there is no other solution than to get an admin to install you an actual full-scale web server.

---

The PSGI protocol and the Plack tools are a simple, easy to use replacement for CGI. They allow you to be very flexible while making it easy to have persistently running large applications.